# Handling of integer with values > 2^32 on Sparc 32 bits

Tags: c, assembly, long-integer, sparc

I coded a little program that measures the time spent into a loop (via an inline Sparc assembly code snippet).

Everything is right until I set number of iterations above roughly 4.0+9 (above 2^32).

Here's the code snippet :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // For indices
  int i;
  // Set the number of executions
  int nRunning = atoi(argv[1]);
  // Set the sums
  double avgSum = 0.0;
  double stdSum = 0.0;
  // Average of execution time
  double averageRuntime = 0.0;
  // Standard deviation of execution time
  double deviationRuntime = 0.0;

  // Init sum
  unsigned long long int sum = 0;
  // Number of iterations
  unsigned long long int nLoop = 4000000000ULL;
  //uint64_t nLoop = 4000000000;
    
  // DEBUG
  printf("sizeof(unsigned long long int) = %zu\n",sizeof(unsigned long long int));
  printf("sizeof(unsigned long int) = %zu\n",sizeof(unsigned long int));

  // Time intervals
  struct timeval tv1, tv2;
  double diff;

  // Loop for multiple executions
  for (i=0; i<nRunning; i++)
  {
   // Start time
   gettimeofday (&tv1, NULL);

   // Loop with Sparc assembly into C source
   asm volatile ("clr %%g1\n\t" 
                 "clr %%g2\n\t" 
                 "mov %1, %%g1\n" // %1 = input parameter
                 "loop:\n\t" 
                 "add %%g2, 1, %%g2\n\t" 
                 "subcc %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t" 
                 "bne loop\n\t" 
                 "nop\n\t" 
                 "mov %%g2, %0\n" // %0 = output parameter
                 : "=r" (sum)     // output
                 : "r" (nLoop)    // input
                 : "g1", "g2");   // clobbers

   // End time
   gettimeofday (&tv2, NULL);

   // Compute runtime for loop
   diff = (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000000ULL + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec);
   
   // Summing diff time
   avgSum += diff;
   stdSum += (diff*diff);

   // DEBUG
   printf("diff = %e\n", diff);
   printf("avgSum = %e\n", avgSum);

  }
  // Compute final averageRuntime   
  averageRuntime = avgSum/nRunning;

  // Compute standard deviation
  deviationRuntime = sqrt(stdSum/nRunning-averageRuntime*averageRuntime);

  // Print results
  printf("(Average Elapsed time, Standard deviation) = %e usec  %e usec\n", averageRuntime, deviationRuntime);
  // Print sum from assembly loop
  printf("Sum = %llu\n", sum);
```

For example, with `nLoop` < 2^32, I get correct values for `diff`, `avgSum` and `stdSum`. Indeed, the `printf` ,with `nLoop = 4.0e+9`, gives :

```
sizeof(unsigned long long int) = 8
sizeof(unsigned long int) = 4
diff = 9.617167e+06
avgSum = 9.617167e+06
diff = 9.499878e+06
avgSum = 1.911704e+07
(Average Elapsed time, Standard deviation) = 9.558522e+06 usec  5.864450e+04 usec
Sum = 4000000000
```

The code is compiled on Debian Sparc 32 bits Etch with `gcc 4.1.2`.

Unfortunately, if I take for example `nLoop = 5.0e+9`, I get small and incorrect values for measured times; here's the printf output in this case :

```
sizeof(unsigned long long int) = 8
sizeof(unsigned long int) = 4
diff = 5.800000e+01
avgSum = 5.800000e+01
diff = 4.000000e+00
avgSum = 6.200000e+01
(Average Elapsed time, Standard deviation) = 3.100000e+01 usec  2.700000e+01 usec
Sum = 5000000000
```

I don't know where the issue could come from, I have done other tests using `uint64_t` but without success.

Maybe the problem is that I handle `large integers (> 2^32)` with 32 bits OS or it may be the assembly inline code which doesn't support 8 bytes integer.

### Update 1

Following the advice of @AndrewHenle, I took the same code but instead of inline Sparc Assembly snippet, I have just put a simple loop.

Here's the program with the simple loop which has got `nLoop = 5.0e+9` (see the line "`unsigned long long int nLoop = 5000000000ULL;`", so above the `limit 2^32-1` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // For indices of nRunning
  int i;
  // For indices of nRunning
  unsigned long long int j;
  // Set the number of executions
  int nRunning = atoi(argv[1]);
  // Set the sums
  unsigned long long int avgSum = 0;
  unsigned long long int stdSum = 0;
  // Average of execution time
  double averageRuntime = 0.0;
  // Standard deviation of execution time
  double deviationRuntime = 0.0;

  // Init sum
  unsigned long long int sum;
  // Number of iterations
  unsigned long long int nLoop = 5000000000ULL;
    
  // DEBUG
  printf("sizeof(unsigned long long int) = %zu\n",sizeof(unsigned long long int));
  printf("sizeof(unsigned long int) = %zu\n",sizeof(unsigned long int));

  // Time intervals
  struct timeval tv1, tv2;
  unsigned long long int diff;

  // Loop for multiple executions
  for (i=0; i<nRunning; i++)
  {
   // Reset sum
   sum = 0;

   // Start time
   gettimeofday (&tv1, NULL);

   // Loop with Sparc assembly into C source
   /* asm volatile ("clr %%g1\n\t" 
                 "clr %%g2\n\t" 
                 "mov %1, %%g1\n" // %1 = input parameter
         "loop:\n\t" 
         "add %%g2, 1, %%g2\n\t" 
         "subcc %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t" 
         "bne loop\n\t" 
         "nop\n\t" 
         "mov %%g2, %0\n" // %0 = output parameter
         : "=r" (sum)     // output
         : "r" (nLoop)    // input
         : "g1", "g2");   // clobbers
   */

   // Classic loop
   for (j=0; j<nLoop; j++)
      sum ++;

   // End time
   gettimeofday (&tv2, NULL);

   // Compute runtime for loop
   diff = (unsigned long long int) ((tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec));
   
   // Summing diff time
   avgSum += diff;
   stdSum += (diff*diff);

   // DEBUG
   printf("diff = %llu\n", diff);
   printf("avgSum = %llu\n", avgSum);
   printf("stdSum = %llu\n", stdSum);
   // Print sum from assembly loop
   printf("Sum = %llu\n", sum);

  }
  // Compute final averageRuntime   
  averageRuntime = avgSum/nRunning;

  // Compute standard deviation
  deviationRuntime = sqrt(stdSum/nRunning-averageRuntime*averageRuntime);

  // Print results
  printf("(Average Elapsed time, Standard deviation) = %e usec  %e usec\n", averageRuntime, deviationRuntime);

  return 0;

}
```

This code snippet is working fine, i.e the variable `sum` is printed as (see "`printf("Sum = %llu\n", sum)`") :

```
Sum = 5000000000
```

So the problem comes from the version with Sparc Assembly block.

I suspect, in this assembly code, the line `"mov %1, %%g1\n" // %1 = input parameter` to badly store `nLoop` into `%g1 register` (I think that `%g1` is a 32 bits register, so can't store values above `2^32-1`).

However, the output parameter (variable `sum`) at the line :

```
"mov %%g2, %0\n" // %0 = output parameter
```

is above the limit since it is equal to 5000000000.

I attach the vimdiff between the version with Assembly loop and without it :

[image: figure]

On the left, program With Assembly, on the right, Without Assembly (just a simple loop instead

I remind you my issue is that, for nLoop > 2^32-1 and with Assembly loop, I get a valid `sum` parameter at the end of execution but not valid (too short) `average` and `standard deviation` times (spent into loop); here's an example of output with `nLoop = 5000000000ULL` :

```
sizeof(unsigned long long int) = 8
sizeof(unsigned long int) = 4
diff = 17
avgSum = 17
stdSum = 289
Sum = 5000000000
diff = 4
avgSum = 21
stdSum = 305
Sum = 5000000000
(Average Elapsed time, Standard deviation) = 1.000000e+01 usec  7.211103e+00 usec
```

With taking `nLoop = 4.0e+9`, i.e `nLoop = 4000000000ULL`, there is no problem, the times values are valid.

### Update 2

I am searching more deeply by generating Assembly code. The version with `nLoop = 4000000000 (4.0e+9)` is below :

```
    .file   "loop-WITH-asm-inline-4-Billions.c"
    .section    ".rodata"
    .align 8
.LLC1:
    .asciz  "sizeof(unsigned long long int) = %zu\n"
    .align 8
.LLC2:
    .asciz  "sizeof(unsigned long int) = %zu\n"
    .align 8
.LLC3:
    .asciz  "diff = %llu\n"
    .align 8
.LLC4:
    .asciz  "avgSum = %llu\n"
    .align 8
.LLC5:
    .asciz  "stdSum = %llu\n"
    .align 8
.LLC6:
    .asciz  "Sum = %llu\n"
    .global __udivdi3
    .global __cmpdi2
    .global __floatdidf
    .align 8
.LLC7:
    .asciz  "(Average Elapsed time, Standard deviation) = %e usec  %e usec\n"
    .align 8
.LLC0:
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .section    ".text"
    .align 4
    .global main
    .type   main, #function
    .proc   04
main:
    save    %sp, -248, %sp
    st  %i0, [%fp+68]
    st  %i1, [%fp+72]
    ld  [%fp+72], %g1
    add %g1, 4, %g1
    ld  [%g1], %g1
    mov %g1, %o0
    call    atoi, 0
     nop
    mov %o0, %g1
    st  %g1, [%fp-68]
    st  %g0, [%fp-64]
    st  %g0, [%fp-60]
    st  %g0, [%fp-56]
    st  %g0, [%fp-52]
    sethi   %hi(.LLC0), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC0), %g1
    ldd [%g1], %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-48]
    sethi   %hi(.LLC0), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC0), %g1
    ldd [%g1], %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-40]
    mov 0, %g2
    sethi   %hi(4000000000), %g3
    std %g2, [%fp-24]
    sethi   %hi(.LLC1), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC1), %o0
    mov 8, %o1
    call    printf, 0
     nop
    sethi   %hi(.LLC2), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC2), %o0
    mov 4, %o1
    call    printf, 0
     nop
    st  %g0, [%fp-84]
    b   .LL2
     nop
.LL3:
    st  %g0, [%fp-32]
    st  %g0, [%fp-28]
    add %fp, -92, %g1
    mov %g1, %o0
    mov 0, %o1
    call    gettimeofday, 0
     nop
    ldd [%fp-24], %o4
    clr %g1
    clr %g2
    mov %o4, %g1
loop:
    add %g2, 1, %g2
    subcc %g1, 1, %g1
    bne loop
    nop
    mov %g2, %o4

    std %o4, [%fp-32]
    add %fp, -100, %g1
    mov %g1, %o0
    mov 0, %o1
    call    gettimeofday, 0
     nop
    ld  [%fp-100], %g2
    ld  [%fp-92], %g1
    sub %g2, %g1, %g2
    sethi   %hi(999424), %g1
    or  %g1, 576, %g1
    smul    %g2, %g1, %g3
    ld  [%fp-96], %g2
    ld  [%fp-88], %g1
    sub %g2, %g1, %g1
    add %g3, %g1, %g1
    st  %g1, [%fp-12]
    sra %g1, 31, %g1
    st  %g1, [%fp-16]
    ldd [%fp-64], %o4
    ldd [%fp-16], %g2
    addcc   %o5, %g3, %g3
    addx    %o4, %g2, %g2
    std %g2, [%fp-64]
    ld  [%fp-16], %g2
    ld  [%fp-12], %g1
    smul    %g2, %g1, %g4
    ld  [%fp-16], %g2
    ld  [%fp-12], %g1
    smul    %g2, %g1, %g1
    add %g4, %g1, %g4
    ld  [%fp-12], %g2
    ld  [%fp-12], %g1
    umul    %g2, %g1, %g3
    rd  %y, %g2
    add %g4, %g2, %g4
    mov %g4, %g2
    ldd [%fp-56], %o4
    addcc   %o5, %g3, %g3
    addx    %o4, %g2, %g2
    std %g2, [%fp-56]
    sethi   %hi(.LLC3), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC3), %o0
    ld  [%fp-16], %o1
    ld  [%fp-12], %o2
    call    printf, 0
     nop
    sethi   %hi(.LLC4), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC4), %o0
    ld  [%fp-64], %o1
    ld  [%fp-60], %o2
    call    printf, 0
     nop
    sethi   %hi(.LLC5), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC5), %o0
    ld  [%fp-56], %o1
    ld  [%fp-52], %o2
    call    printf, 0
     nop
    sethi   %hi(.LLC6), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC6), %o0
    ld  [%fp-32], %o1
    ld  [%fp-28], %o2
    call    printf, 0
     nop
    ld  [%fp-84], %g1
    add %g1, 1, %g1
    st  %g1, [%fp-84]
.LL2:
    ld  [%fp-84], %g2
    ld  [%fp-68], %g1
    cmp %g2, %g1
    bl  .LL3
     nop
    ld  [%fp-68], %g1
    sra %g1, 31, %g1
    ld  [%fp-68], %g3
    mov %g1, %g2
    ldd [%fp-64], %o0
    mov %g2, %o2
    mov %g3, %o3
    call    __udivdi3, 0
     nop
    mov %o0, %g2
    mov %o1, %g3
    std %g2, [%fp-136]
    ldd [%fp-136], %o0
    mov 0, %o2
    mov 0, %o3
    call    __cmpdi2, 0
     nop
    mov %o0, %g1
    cmp %g1, 1
    bl  .LL6
     nop
    ldd [%fp-136], %o0
    call    __floatdidf, 0
     nop
    std %f0, [%fp-144]
    b   .LL5
     nop
.LL6:
    ldd [%fp-136], %o4
    and %o4, 0, %g2
    and %o5, 1, %g3
    ld  [%fp-136], %o5
    sll %o5, 31, %g1
    ld  [%fp-132], %g4
    srl %g4, 1, %o5
    or  %o5, %g1, %o5
    ld  [%fp-136], %g1
    srl %g1, 1, %o4
    or  %g2, %o4, %g2
    or  %g3, %o5, %g3
    mov %g2, %o0
    mov %g3, %o1
    call    __floatdidf, 0
     nop
    std %f0, [%fp-144]
    ldd [%fp-144], %f8
    ldd [%fp-144], %f10
    faddd   %f8, %f10, %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-144]
.LL5:
    ldd [%fp-144], %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-48]
    ld  [%fp-68], %g1
    sra %g1, 31, %g1
    ld  [%fp-68], %g3
    mov %g1, %g2
    ldd [%fp-56], %o0
    mov %g2, %o2
    mov %g3, %o3
    call    __udivdi3, 0
     nop
    mov %o0, %g2
    mov %o1, %g3
    std %g2, [%fp-128]
    ldd [%fp-128], %o0
    mov 0, %o2
    mov 0, %o3
    call    __cmpdi2, 0
     nop
    mov %o0, %g1
    cmp %g1, 1
    bl  .LL8
     nop
    ldd [%fp-128], %o0
    call    __floatdidf, 0
     nop
    std %f0, [%fp-120]
    b   .LL7
     nop
.LL8:
    ldd [%fp-128], %o4
    and %o4, 0, %g2
    and %o5, 1, %g3
    ld  [%fp-128], %o5
    sll %o5, 31, %g1
    ld  [%fp-124], %g4
    srl %g4, 1, %o5
    or  %o5, %g1, %o5
    ld  [%fp-128], %g1
    srl %g1, 1, %o4
    or  %g2, %o4, %g2
    or  %g3, %o5, %g3
    mov %g2, %o0
    mov %g3, %o1
    call    __floatdidf, 0
     nop
    std %f0, [%fp-120]
    ldd [%fp-120], %f8
    ldd [%fp-120], %f10
    faddd   %f8, %f10, %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-120]
.LL7:
    ldd [%fp-48], %f8
    ldd [%fp-48], %f10
    fmuld   %f8, %f10, %f8
    ldd [%fp-120], %f10
    fsubd   %f10, %f8, %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-112]
    ldd [%fp-112], %f8
    fsqrtd  %f8, %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-152]
    ldd [%fp-152], %f10
    ldd [%fp-152], %f8
    fcmpd   %f10, %f8
    nop
    fbe .LL9
     nop
    ldd [%fp-112], %o0
    call    sqrt, 0
     nop
    std %f0, [%fp-152]
.LL9:
    ldd [%fp-152], %f8
    std %f8, [%fp-40]
    sethi   %hi(.LLC7), %g1
    or  %g1, %lo(.LLC7), %o0
    ld  [%fp-48], %o1
    ld  [%fp-44], %o2
    ld  [%fp-40], %o3
    ld  [%fp-36], %o4
    call    printf, 0
     nop
    mov 0, %g1
    mov %g1, %i0
    restore
    jmp %o7+8
     nop
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack"
```

When I generate the Assembly code version with `nLoop = 5000000000 (5.0e+9)`, the differences are illustrated on the following figure (with `vimdiff`) :

[image: vimdiff differences]

the block of "4 Billions" version :

```
mov     0, %g2                                                                                                                           
sethi   %hi(4000000000), %g3
```

is replaced in "5 Billions" version by :

```
 mov     1, %g2
 sethi   %hi(705032192), %g3                                                   
 or      %g3, 512, %g3
```

I can see that `5.0+e9` can't be coded on 32 bits, since the instruction

```
sethi   %hi(705032192), %g3
```

Paradoxically, when I compile the version "5 Billions" Assembly code, the ouput parameter `sum` is computed well, i.e is equal to `5 Billions`, and I can't explain it.

Comment: You seem to access `sum` in your assembler code which is `unsigned long long`. Of course you have to adapt your asm code to match the size and type of your parameters. Did you try to use C code and let the compiler to the work? If the compiler supports 8 byte integer values it can create code to manipulate them.

Comment: @Gerhardh- If you look at the printf output, you can see that `sum` is computed well (=4.0e+9 for first example and 5.0e+9 for second one). In both cases, `sum` is declared as `unsigned long long int` . I don't understand why this is not the same case with using `nLoop > 2^32` in assembly input parameter ?

Comment: Does you assembly code do the 64 bits calculations? You probably do not

Comment: @PeterJ- How to know if assembly code does the 64 bits calculations ? the line `"add %%g2, 1, %%g2\n\t"`seems to do it because output parameter (sum) at the end of assembly code gives values over 2^32 (4.0e+9 with valid times and 5.0e+9 with incorrect times).

Comment: To hunt down the problem you might print the results of `tv1` and `tv2` and verify the range of the difference.

Comment: Look at `int nRunning = ...; printf("avgSum = %e\n", avgSum); averageRuntime = avgSum/nRunning; printf("(Average Elapsed time, Standard deviation) = %e usec  ...\n", averageRuntime, ...);` and output `9.617167e+06, 9.558522e+06`.  This makes no sense.  Is this true code and true output?  Else, I think you have memory corruption due to `asm()`.

Comment: @chux- sorry, I forgot to precise that I have taken `nRunning=2` at the execution (**./a.out 2**), this is the argument of executable. `9.558522e+06` is the average of these 2 executions and `5.864450e+04`the standard deviation.

Comment: What *actual* instructions are produced?  For example, `mov` on SPARC is a synthetic instruction that's actually implemented as one or more *other* instructions, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/816-1681/instructionset-86762/index.html.  I'd recommend getting it working **without** hand-jammed ASM code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on what version of sparc and what ABI your are using.  If you are using sparc v8 or earlier, you have 32 bit mode with only 32 bit registers.  In which case when you try to load 5000000000 into a 32-bit register it fails and loads 5000000000 mod 2<sup>32</sup> instead (which is 705032704).  This is what appears to be happening.

If on the other hand you have a 64-bit sparc processor running in 32 bit mode (what is usually called v8plus), then you can use 64 bit registers, so this would work.

Comment: -@Chris Dodd I am using  Debian Sparc 32 bits Etch (with gcc 4.1.2) from an image with QEMU. ( the image is available on https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/sparc/ ). From what you say, I have to create a QEMU image of Debian Sparc 64 bits instead of 32 bits. I found on https://people.debian.org/~glaubitz/debian-cd/2017-03-24/ a iso image of Debian-9 Sparc 64 bits. How to create a QEMU image from this iso under MacOS 10.9.5 : I tried to do : qemu-system-sparc -hda debian_stretch_sparc64.img debian-9.0-sparc64-NETINST-1.iso -boot d but I get error and it doesn't generate ".img" file

Comment: I have also tried to do : qemu-system-sparc -hda debian_stretch_sparc64.img -cdrom debian-9.0-sparc64-NETINST-1.iso -boot d . How to avoid the "-cdrom" flag when one hasn't got a cdrom ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing 32-bit operations on one-half of a 64-bit value

From the generated code, here's where `nLoop` is a **double-load** into both `%o4` and `%o5` (since it's a 64-bit `long long` value):

```
    ldd [%fp-24], %o4
    clr %g1
    clr %g2
```

And then you just work with `%o4`:

```
    mov %o4, %g1                ; <---- what about %o5????
loop:
    add %g2, 1, %g2
    subcc %g1, 1, %g1
    bne loop
    nop
    mov %g2, %o4
```

To make this work, re-write your assembly code to treat `%o4` + `%o5` together as a 64-bit value.